# converting a String to type UTCTime

Tags: types, haskell

I'm writing a `getSitemapR` handler that uses yesod-sitemap to generate a sitemap file. The issue I'm having is converting a `String` into `UTCTime` as defined in `Data.Time.Clock`. The haddock documentation says that `UTCTime` is an instance of the `Read` typeclass, so that's what I'm trying. Here's my code.

```
module Handler.Root where

import Import
import Yesod.Goodies.Gravatar
import Data.Time.Format
import System.Locale
-- This is a handler function for the GET request method on the RootR
-- resource pattern. All of your resource patterns are defined in
-- config/routes
--
-- The majority of the code you will write in Yesod lives in these handler
-- functions. You can spread them across multiple files if you are so
-- inclined, or create a single monolithic file.
getRootR :: Handler RepHtml
getRootR = do
    defaultLayout $ do
        h2id <- lift newIdent
        setTitle "Cloudrr homepage"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")

gravatar :: Text -> String
gravatar email = 
  gravatarImg email go
  where
    go = GravatarOptions {
      gSize = Just (Size 140)
      , gDefault = Just (Identicon)
      , gForceDefault = ForceDefault False
      , gRating = Just (PG)
      }

getSitemapR :: Handler RepXml
getSitemapR = do
  sitemap [smo RootR]
  where
    smo = SitemapUrl  SitemapR{
      sitemapLoc = "http://www.cloudrr.me/sitemap.xml"
      , sitemapLastMod = (read "2011-11-19 18:28:r52.607875 UTC")::UTCTime
      , sitemapChangeFreq = Weekly
      , priority = 0.7
      }
```

I've looked through my copy of *Real World Haskell* in chapter 20 on systems programming, but it doesn't cover `UTCTime` in it's code samples, I've searched google with the term 'haskell "Convert a String to UTCTime"' with no results. I found the following [Thread](http://osdir.com/ml/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/2011-06/msg00586.html) in the haskell-cafe mailing list which won't work because `SitemapLastMod` doesn't take a `Maybe UTCTime`. I think I'm making a really stupid mistake here, but I'm not sure, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Are you using `read` and it just crashes, or will the code not compile? Can you clearly state where you got stuck?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
, sitemapLastMod = (read "2011-11-19 18:28:r52.607875 UTC")::UTCTime
```

The lower case `r` should not be there. Try

```
, sitemapLastMod = (read "2011-11-19 18:28:52.607875 UTC")::UTCTime
```